# How we can check the balance of the account in any pallet?

Tags: pallet, balances

I am developing a pallet in which I need to check the balance of the account that is making the transaction. How can I check that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way is:

```rs
ensure!(T::Currency::free_balance(&who) >= some_value, <Error<T>>::InsufficientBalance);
```

Comment: `reducible_balance` should be more accurate will deduct locked&ed if necessary